# Hot-cold high availability for Corda OS

Tags: corda

Corda Enterprise has Hot-cold high availability deployment feature.https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.2/hot-cold-deployment.html

It is possible to use that for Corda open source 4.3?

Any advice for improve availability with Corda open source 4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Docker Corda OS 4.3 in a HA k8s cluster that should to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the HA feature is not available with Corda Open Source.

Comment: how about "additionalP2PAddress "  fields in node.conf ?.This document says that " Nodes can use this configuration option to advertise HA endpoints and aliases to external parties."